# C# communicate with CLI process

Tags: c#, process, command-line-interface

I want to run a process in the Windows console, after that, I want to pass (with button click) some commands and see the result in a RichTextBox.

I’m able to launch the program and read the responses after starting, but when I try to send any commands, it doesn’t work: I’m not able to communicate with the process.

Below the code:

```
public static void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
    // Collect the sort command output.
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) {
        numOutputLines++;
        // Add the text to the collected output.
        sortOutput.Append(Environment.NewLine + $"[{numOutputLines}] - {outLine.Data}");
        //RichTextBox
        MCM.ActiveForm.Invoke(MCM.AffichageTextDelegate, new object[] { outLine.Data });
    }
}
   
public static async Task<int> RunProcessAsync() {
    using (var process = new Process {
        StartInfo = {
            FileName = "AAA.exe",
            Arguments = “-v COM74",
            UseShellExecute = false, 
            CreateNoWindow = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true 
    })
    { return await RunProcessAsync(process).ConfigureAwait(false); }
}

private static Task<int> RunProcessAsync(Process process) {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    
    process.Exited += (s, ea) => tcs.SetResult(process.ExitCode);
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine(ea.Data);
    sortOutput = new StringBuilder();
    process.OutputDataReceived += SortOutputHandler;
    process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine("ERR: " + ea.Data);
    
    process.Start();
    
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    
    return tcs.Task;
}

private async void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await RunProcessAsync();
}
```

Comment: How are you sending commands to the process?

Comment: I tried : Console.WriteLine. It is written in console, but the process doesn't answer. When I'm using StandardInput it doesn't work, I think it's because I restart a new process, I'm not writing inside the first one.

Answer (score 0):

It's working with a synchronous process :

```
public static Process myProcess;
public static StreamWriter myStreamWriter;

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "AAA.exe";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = '-' + "p" + " " + ComboBoxPortCom.Text;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine(ea.Data);
        sortOutput = new StringBuilder();
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += SortOutputHandler;
        myProcess.ErrorDataReceived += (s, ea) => Console.WriteLine("ERR: " + ea.Data);
        
        myProcess.Start();

        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
        myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;

        myStreamWriter.WriteLine("Command1" + '\n');
```